# I'm facing issue in UrlEncode() in class library

Tags: c#

I'm facing an issue in `UrlEncode()` in class library. The issue is

> Dictionary<string, dynamic> doesnot contain a definition for UrlEncode and no accessible extension method UrlEncode accepting first element of type Dictionary<string, dynamic> could be found.

I already took the `UrlEncode()` function.

```cs
public static string UrlEncode( Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters)
{
    return string.Join("&", parameters.Select(x => $"{ x.Key }={ WebUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value) }"));
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I think you mean `UrlEncode(data)`

Comment: @John yes almost

Comment: This is about the time you should research extension methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: I am tempted to vote to close as a typo.

Answer (score 3):

The way you call it, it seems you want it to be an extension method. So you need to add the `this` keyword in the place where you suspiciously left an unnecessary blank:

```
public static string UrlEncode(this Dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters)

                                 ^
                                 |
```

Comment: @john When I add this in that I'm getting same error and I also got error at class.

Comment: The class needs to be `static` to contain that method.

Comment: Yaa If I add static class means error will gone but  I'm geting error at main class because of class extension.Like this  public class Class1 : CodeActivity. Im getting error at class1 If i give static

Comment: Make a new static class, place the method inside it.

Comment: Well, why derive this from anything ?

Comment: @nvoigt because i need to convert this code to custom workflow

Comment: No you don't. This method can be all by itself in a single static class.

Comment: @John Make a new static class, place the method inside it...Thanx john it worked for me.